# synchronous httpservice requests in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

Is it possible to make httpService Requests synchronous in Flex?

if yes pls tell me how to do this.

It was asked to me in an interview.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean something where `httpService.send()` returns only after the service is completed? - To the best of my knowledge, No.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well hang on, I mean it depends - you couldn't do it in a functional way, but if we're talking strictly theoretical then you could hack something like this:

```
var returned:Boolean = false;

function syncService():void {
     httpService.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
     httpService.send();

     while (!returned) {}

     return;
}

function completeHandler(e:Event):void {
     returned = true;
}
```

I'd never use that in production and it might not even work. It's just asking for time-out errors etc - but in theory that should do it, right?

Comment: That will not work. ActionScript runs in a single thread, and it will just get stuck in your while loop, never calling the completeHandler, and never drawing to the screen again.